# c++ const pointer with operator[]

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-keyword

```
char* const p = "world";
p[2] = 'l';
```

The first statement creates a string pointed by a const pointer p, and the second statement tries to modify the string, and it is accepted by the compiler, while in the running time, an access violation exception is poped, and could anyone explain why?

Comment: What you want is char p[] = "world" instead of char * const p

Comment: Actually, it's an interview question, I just wonder why it is illegal. I think @Elemental hits the point: you can't change literals in runtime. And I found that even char* p = "world"; also causes a failure.

Comment: Either as cerkiewny says (which copies the literal to a local buffer, which you can change safely) or you should use `const char *p = "world";` which prevents attempts to modify the literal at compile-time. Notice the const is on the left-hand side of the * symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your question is two-fold:

1. Why does it give an access violation: character literal strings are stored as literals in the CODE pages of your executable program; most modern operating system do not allow changes to the these pages (including  MS-windows) thus the protection fault.
2. Why does the compiler allow it: the const keyword in this context refers to the pointer and not the thing it points at. Code such as p="Hello"; will cause a compiler error as you have declared p as constant (not *p). If you wanted to declare the thing it points to as constant then your declaration should be const char *p.

Comment: He described the pointer to be the constant not the value stored in under memory pointed, so he wants (const char *).

Comment: There’s some confusion here. The data memory is protected but it’s very unlikely to be in the code segment. Also, this explains why the code fails in practice, but it doesn’t explain why this “unhelpful” behaviour is allowed by C++.

Answer (score 3):

In the

```
  char* const p = "World";
```

P points to const character array, which resides in the .rodata memory area. So, one can not modify the data pointed by the p variable and one cannot change the p to point to some other string as well.

Comment: If he had done `char[] str = "World"; char* const p = &str;` could he then modify it?

Comment: @crush - no - same problem - the underlying data is stored in a memory page that the OS will not allow modification to. This really has little to do with the compiler and more to do with how the linker arranges memory and the operating system.

Comment: @Elemental I see! what if he copied `str` into another `char[]`, then pointed to that new `char[]`! then surely he could modify it

Comment: @crush If you actually mean `char str[] = "World"` then yes, it copies the literal into a local buffer called str which can be modified.

Comment: @crush yep - that is how I understand it.

Comment: @Elemental It is safe to do that, if the syntax is corrected.

Comment: Wow, @crush proposes another interesting problem! I test char[] case, and it works!

Answer (score 1):

```
char* const p = "world";
```

This is illegal in the current C++ standard (C++11). Most compilers still accept it because they use the previous C++ standard (C++03) by default, but even there the code is *deprecated*, and a good compiler with the right warning level should warn about this.

The reason is that the type of the literal `"world"` is `char const[6]`. In other words, a literal is always *constant* and cannot be changed. When you say …

```
char* const p = "world";
```

… then the compiler *converts* the literal into a pointer. This is done implicitly by an operation called “array decay”: a C array can be implicitly converted into a pointer that points to its beginning.

So `"world"` is converted into a value of type `char const*`. Notice the `const` – we still are not allowed to change the literal, even when accessed through the pointer.

Alas, C++03 also allows that literals be assigned to a *non*-`const` pointer to provide backwards compatibility with C.

Since this is an interview question, the correct answer is thus: the code is illegal and the compiler shouldn’t allow it. Here’s the corrected code:

```
char const* const p = "world";
//p[2] = 'l'; // Not allowed!
```

We’ve used *two* `const`s here: the first is required for the literal. The second makes the pointer itself (rather than the pointed-to value) `const`.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is if you define a string literal like this:

```
char * p = "some text"
```

the compiler will prepare memory for pointer only, and the text location
will be by default set to .text section

in the other hand if you define it as:

```
char p[] = "some text"
```

the compiler will know that you want the memory for entire character array.

In the first case you can't read the value as the MMU is set to readonly access for the .text section of memory, in the 2nd case you can freely access and modify memory.

Another think (to prevent the runtime error) would be correct describing of the memory the pointer points to.

For the constant pointer it would be:

```
const char * const p = "blaaaah"
```

and for the normal one:

```
const char * p = "blaah"
```

Comment: `char p[]` is not on the heap.

Comment: @NeilKirk yea, your right, its treated as automated variable if it would be global i would be putted into .bss section

Answer (score -2):

```
char* const p = "world";
```

Here p is a pointer with constant memory address. So this will compile fine as there is no syntax error as per compiler and it throws exception in runtime bcoz as its a constant pointer you can change its value.

[C++ reference constant pointers](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/pointers/const_pointers.html)

[Const correctness](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/const_correctness.html)

Comment: Pointer p is not changed. `p[2]` does not change the value of p.